# Understding shared_ptr

Tags: c++, memory-management

I'm reading Scott Meyerses C++ and now at the section about managing resources. He explains that the shared-ptr is a reference counting smart pointer and that it acts like a garbage collector except that it can't ***break cycles of reference***. What does it mean? What is the breaking cycles of references?

Comment: If A has a `shared_ptr` to B, and B has a `shared_ptr` to A, that's a cycle.

Comment: @MarkRansom I would like to see that in a real world example, what a nice design that would be

Comment: @newone I don't have a concrete example, but you can see it when you want a parent that has a pointer to a child but the child needs a pointer to its parent, as just one example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
struct A
{
    shared_ptr<A> p ;
} ;

if ( true ) // complete extra scope for this example, just to make these things go out of scope
{
    shared_ptr<A> p1 = make_shared<A>() ;
    shared_ptr<A> p2 = make_shared<A>() ;

    p1->p = p2 ;
    p2->p = p1 ;
}
// At this point, they're out of scope and clearly won't be used again
// However, they will NOT be destroyed because they both have a strong reference to each other
```

This is a cycle.

A garbage collector (which has knowledge of the system) can see that those variables aren't referenced by anything, so clearly they're not needed, and will destroy them. A garbage collector can [generally] run whenever it wants to.

However, in C++, some code actually has to perform that action... but nothing ever will.

### Where do you use this?

Large programs.

Firstly, I'd like to propose a couple definitions:

- Structure: a thing that holds data (like a position or a record of time, position, velocity, etc) - i.e a thing you're meant to *use* and has minimal smarts to it. *(Sidenote: I tend to declare these using 'struct')*
- Object: a thing which controls its data and has a state which you interact with by a conversation (like calling methods or sending messages) - i.e. a thing which acts like an *agent* (or, a thing that you talk to, like a database). *(Sidenote: I tend to declare these using 'class')*

It rarely makes sense for a structure to have shared pointers to other structures in a recursive fashion.

However, let's say you have an object:

```
class Database
{
public:
    // ...
    void shared_ptr<Record> recordNamed ( string const& name ) const ;
private:
    map<string,shared_ptr<Record> > mRecords ;
    //                           ^ so irritating
} ;

class Record
{
public:
    shared_ptr<Database> parentDatabase () const ;
    void reloadFromDataStore () const ; // reloads props from database
private:
    shared_ptr<Database> mpParentDatabase ;
    // maybe other data here too...
} ;

shared_ptr<Database> db = ... ; // get it from somewhere
shared_ptr<Record> record = db->recordNamed ( "christopher" ) ;
```

This is a real-world case where you'd want to have circular references, and it is *absolutely* a valid one.

In a garbage-collected environment, this is perfectly fine because the GC knows who's using what and will know these aren't being used later.

In C++, the reference-count never goes to zero (because two living objects both point to each other) and *there is no code to come back through and realize otherwise (if there were, it would be called a garbage collector!)*.

You'll read after `shared_ptr` about `weak_ptr`, which solves this issue.

Here's one way to use it:

```
class Database
{
public:
    // ...
    void shared_ptr<Record> recordNamed ( string const& name ) const ;
private:
    map<string,shared_ptr<Record> > mRecords ;
} ;

class Record
{
public:
    shared_ptr<Database> parentDatabase () const ;
    void reloadFromDataStore () const ; // reloads props from database
private:
    weak_ptr<Database> mpParentDatabase ; // don't hold onto it strongly
    // maybe other data here too...
} ;

shared_ptr<Database> db = ... ; // get it from somewhere
shared_ptr<Record> record = db->recordNamed ( "christopher" ) ;
```

However, what happens if you do this?

```
db.reset() ; // removes the last strong-reference to the database, so it is destroyed!
db = record->parentDatabase() ; // tries to lock the weak_ptr, but fails because it's dead! So it can only return null, or throw an exception.
```

What if instead you put the `weak_ref` somewhere else?

```
class Database
{
public:
    // ...
    void shared_ptr<Record> recordNamed ( string const& name ) const ;
private:
    map<string,weak_ptr<Record> > mRecords ;
} ;

class Record
{
public:
    shared_ptr<Database> parentDatabase () const ;
    void reloadFromDataStore () const ; // reloads props from database
private:
    shared_ptr<Database> mpParentDatabase ;
    // maybe other data here too...
} ;

shared_ptr<Database> db = ... ; // get it from somewhere
shared_ptr<Record> record = db->recordNamed ( "christopher" ) ;
```

In this case, the `Database` only has weak references to its records... but that means it has to go create it from a store every time it needs something that isn't currently alive. This would work with file-based database, but not if the database is something that lives purely in memory as part of your program.

### Solution A

Add a command like this:

```
db->close() ; // removes all references to Records and resets their references to the database
```

### Solution B

Have a "token" that owns the lifespan of everything:

```
shared_ptr<LifespanToken> token = ... ;

Database* ptr = new Database ( token ) ;
Record * record = ptr->recordNamed ( "christopher" ) ;
```

The idea being that the token owns the lifespan. This is the manual way to get around the retain-cycle issue, but this requires you to know how people will use the system! You have to know a LOT up front. This can make sense in the context of a database, but you would *not* want to have to do this for every last piece of your code. Thankfully, cycles come up mostly in contexts that CAN do this, and most of them can be fixed with `weak_ptr`.

Comment: So, in your example we end up in memory leaks?

Comment: @stella yes baby thats what's going on, but no one designs a program like that and you rarely need a shared_ptr.

Comment: @newone - that's patently false; shared_ptr is used a LOT. Technically, you're right: they're not needed. You *can* determine the lifespans of everything, but you'll triple your development time. And cycles come up out of necessity (that's one reason garbage collectors exist!), which is the genesis of weak_ptr.

Comment: @iAdjunct That's why i wanted to see one real world example in a software where you actually need a shared_ptr and on top of that, circular dependency. In my opinion that's a design flaw. Are you talking about this happening in home-made projects or in commercial softwares? I have yet to come across something like that...

Comment: @newone - What I do isn't "home-made", but it wouldn't really be "commercial" either. But trust me: it's big (and important). We can't afford to be wasting our time letting something as trivial as memory management take up 50% of our development time - we have better things to do. I've added one detailed-example to my post of when cycles *will* come up.